# Compare year from DateTimeField/DateField Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-database-functions

I have a model configuration as below,

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
```

How can I retrieve **`Foo`** instances with **same Year**?

---

Unsuccessfull try:

```
from django.db.models import F

Foo.objects.filter(start__year=F('end__year'))
```

returnd empty **`QuerySet`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL query of `Foo.objects.filter(start__year=F('end__year'))` statement is,

```
SELECT "foo"."id", "foo"."start", "foo"."end" 
FROM "foo" 
WHERE django_datetime_extract('year', "foo"."start", 'UTC') = ("foo"."end")
```

See..? The comparison takes place between the integer (the extracted `start year`) and datetime (`end datetime`)

So, Django returned empty `QuerySet`.

What's the solution?

We could use [`ExtractYear()` db function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractYear) to extract `Year` from `DateTimeField` and use `annotate()` function to store it tempoparily. Then compare the annotated field against the year lookup.

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractYear

Foo.objects.annotate(start_year=ExtractYear(F('start'))).filter(<b>end__year=F('start_year'))
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    "foo"."id", "foo"."start", "foo"."end", 
    django_datetime_extract('year', "foo"."start", 'UTC') AS "start_year" 
FROM 
    "foo" 
WHERE 
    django_datetime_extract('year', "foo"."end", 'UTC') = (django_datetime_extract('year', "foo"."start", 'UTC'))
```

Comment: seems like a bug in `F()`, because it should not ignore `_year`. Am I reading this wrong?

Comment: In older version of Django, I got invalid lookup error.

Comment: which makes more sense if it is not supported